# p tag messing up layout in CSS

Tags: html, css, layout

Cannot understand why the following is happening:

[image: Before]

Just adding a p tag inside a div causes it to drop down and I can't find a reason for or fix this behaviour:

[image: After]

Code:

```css
html{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}



#BoxContainer{
    border: 5px solid black;
        box-sizing: border-box;
}


#Box1{
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

#Box2{
    background-color: blue;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
}

#Box3{
    background-color: yellow;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    
}

p{
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="testSite">
        <meta name="keywords" content="Responsive Design">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    </head>
    
<body>
<div id="BoxContainer">
    
    <div id="Box1"></div>
    <div id="Box2"></div> 
    <div id="Box3"></div>
    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried removing the margin from p and displaying as inline to no avail.
Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Yep, but it's not the p tag that causes it, it's the "hello" text.

Comment: Yes it also happens without the p tag. The only way this stops happening is if I make the p tags position absolute so that it's out of normal document flow.
My issue is why it's happening in the first place, shouldn't the p tag only take up space within its parent element?

Comment: Note that in the question to which this is a duplicate, the resolution to the misalignment is in the question. Use `vertical-align:top` on your inline-blocks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add `#BoxContainer > *{vertical-align:top;}` and it will fix it.

---

```css
html{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}



#BoxContainer{
    border: 5px solid black;
        box-sizing: border-box;
}

#BoxContainer > *{vertical-align:top;}

#Box1{
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

#Box2{
    background-color: blue;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
}

#Box3{
    background-color: yellow;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    
}

p{
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="testSite">
        <meta name="keywords" content="Responsive Design">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    </head>
    
<body>
<div id="BoxContainer">
    
    <div id="Box1">g</div>
    <div id="Box2"></div> 
    <div id="Box3"></div>
    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
My question was why does it happen though, I had a work around already.

I can't see a reason why text inside the div was suddenly taking up space outside of it.

Comment: @Zeruko fair enough. I see that there is already an duplicate answer that explains exactly that. so i will delete my answer in a bit